# What are mutable Classes. How can we create a mutable and immutable class in C#

Tags: c#-4.0

I was asked in a CMMI level 5 company interview about how to create a mutable and immutable class in C#. I have heard of mutable and immutable which means **can change** and **cannot change**, like **String** and **StringBuilder**.

But, I was not aware of how to create a mutable class and immutable class. We have String and String builder for this. But when it comes to creating one, I was forced to search the web for this, but couldn't find anything useful, so thought of asking here.

However, I tried creating it by defining a property in the class and on its Getter, I created a new object of string to replicate it. But was not successful in understanding.

Also, I have referred that a question is already asked in stackoverflow about immutable and mutable. But, my question is different. I wanted to know if I wanted to create a mutable class then how will I go with it apart from using String or other mutable classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between mutable and immutable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811016/what-is-the-difference-between-mutable-and-immutable)

Comment: Please search for an answer before you post so you don't ask a duplicate question.

Comment: @walther: Please read my question!! I asked how to create a mutable class. I know what are mutable and immutable. but when it comes to creating, i don't know about it. and the question you mentioned is different!!

Comment: If you knew what it is, you wouldn't have any problems creating one. There are examples all over the Internet. I seriously fail to see where exactly is your problem and how is it unique compared to other questions concerning the same subject.

Comment: @Yash I have to ask - "class" as in object type or object instance?

Comment: This, beside the answer below, may help https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lucabol/2007/12/03/creating-an-immutable-value-object-in-c-part-i-using-a-class/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE:

As of late 2020, C# 9.0 for .NET 5.0 has been released which supports immutable record types (with support for copy-constructors, and with the `with` operator to easily create new instances with new property values).

### Original answer, written before C# 9.0 (and 8.0) was released:

C# does not have the same level of support for `const`-correctness that C++ offers (ignoring Code Contracts), but it does still provide for the `readonly` modifier (and true read-only auto-properties in C# 6.0) which helps.

C# also lacks syntactic support for Record types, which unfortunately were pulled from C# 7, so we'll have to wait another year for that (**Update:** As of mid-2018, C# 8.0 is expected to have Record types, but C# 8.0 probably won't be finally released until into 2020 given [its very long list of new features](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/milestone/8)).

Anyway, an immutable type in .NET is just a POCO<sup>1</sup> which cannot have its state modified after construction. Note that this is only enforced by the compiler if your type has every field tagged as `readonly` and that every complex (i.e. non-scalar) member is also similarly constrained.

If your type has any array members then the type cannot be truly immutable because there is no enforcement of read-only buffers in C# (C++ does). Which means in-practice that an "immutable" type in C# is just a well-designed POCO that a consumer (who would be playing by the rules (e.g. no reflection)) can make certain assumptions about when using it, for example, an immutable type is inherently thread-safe. But that's it. There are no special AOT or JIT optimisations nor any special behaviour exhibited by the runtime. It's a very "human factors"-kinda thing.

This class below is immutable:

```
class Immutable {
    private readonly String foo;

    public Immutable(String foo, String bar) {
        this.foo = foo;
        this.Bar = bar;
    }

    public String Bar { get: }

    public String Baz { get { return this.foo.Substring( 0, 2 ); } }
}
```

It is immutable because every field (i.e. its instance-state) is both `readonly` and immutable (we only know this because `System.String` is well known to be immutable). If `foo` were changed to `StringBuilder` or `XmlElement` then it would no longer be immutable.

Note that strictly speaking, the `readonly` modifier is not necessary for immutability, it just makes it easier to demonstrate, and it does add some level of compile-time enforcement (and *possibly* some runtime optimisation).

For comparison's sake, this class is not immutable (i.e. it is mutable):

```
class Mutable {
    private readonly Int32[] values;
    public Mutable(Int32 values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public Int32[] GetValues() {
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

It is mutable because:

1. `Int32[]` (an array type) is mutable
2. It returns a reference to the mutable array via `GetValues`
3. It accepts a mutable object parameter during construction.

Here's an example demonstrating why it's not immutable:

```
Int32[] values = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
Mutable mutable = new Mutable( values );

Print( mutable.GetValues() ); // prints "0, 1, 2, 3"

values[0] = 5;

Print( mutable.GetValues() ); // prints "5, 1, 2, 3"
```

If `Mutable` were immutable then subsequent changes to `values` would not be visible when using `Mutable`'s API: the second call to `Print` would display the same output as the first.

However, you can have an immutable type even if you are using arrays or complex types: and this is done by that hiding all the ways to modify state. For example, return `ReadOnlyCollection<Int32>` instead of `Int32[]` and always perform a deep copy/clone of all complex and mutable values passed-in. But the compiler, JIT, and runtime are still not sophisticated enough to determine this renders the object type immutable - hence why you have to document it and trust your consumer to use it properly (or if you're a consumer, trust your upstream dev that they implemented it correctly)

Here's an example of an immutable type that contains an array:

```
class Immutable {
    private readonly Int32[] values;
    public Mutable(Int32 values) {
        if( values == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(values)); 
        this.values = (Int32[])values.Clone();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Int32> GetValues() {
        return this.values;
    }
}
```

- The input array is shallow-copied (using `Array.Clone()`) during construction - so any future changes to the object passed into the constructor won't affect any `Immutable` class instances.

  - If the `values` array contained non-immutable, non-scalar values then the constructor would have to perform a "deep-copy" of the elements to ensure its values would be isolated from any future changes elsewhere.
- The `values` array is never directly exposed to consumers.
- `GetValues()` returns an `IReadOnlyList<T>` *view* of the internal array (this is new in .NET 4.5). This is more lightweight than returning a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` wrapper (introduced in .NET 2.0).

---

<sup>1</sup>: A POCO is a "Plain Old CLR Object" type, which in-practice means any `class` or `struct` without any requirements that it inherit some parent supertype or implement any particular interface. The term is often used in reference to ORM libraries like Linq-to-SQL, Entity Framework or NHibernate which (in their earlier versions) required each entity class to derive from some base entity type, or employ certain techniques (e.g. `INotifyPropertyChanged`). See here for more details: [What is POCO in Entity Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075245/what-is-poco-in-entity-framework)

Comment: Thank you Dai. It really helped

Comment: @Yash I have significantly extended my answer since you posted.

Comment: It was perfectly explained by using the readonly keyword by ensuring that it can only be set in the constructor. Also, this will prevent from accidentally modifying one of the fields, breaking the immutability.

Comment: @Yash no, that's not my point. The `readonly` keyword does not guarantee immutability, that's why I provided a counter-example with the `Mutable` class.

Comment: I understand your point that readonly keyword does not provide immutability, i was just talking with the code perceptive.

Comment: What is a POCO?

Comment: @user3207158 I've edited my answer to explain what a POCO is.

Comment: "strictly speaking, the readonly modifier is not necessary for immutability" - true in that example but false for public fields