# What's the difference between a ConcurrentDictionary and an ImmutableDictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, dictionary

I am reading *Concurrency in C# Cookbook* and the book told me that:

> `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` is best when you have multiple
>   threads reading and writing to a shared collection. If the updates are
>   not constant (if they’re more rare), than `ImmutableDictionary<TKey,TValue>` 
>   may be a better choice.

I know that Add or Remove a large immutable collection can be slow, and my question is, is there any other difference between them? Now that they are all thread safe, why is `ImmutableDictionary` a better choice when the updates are not constant?

Comment: A `ConcurrentDictionary` is not immutable. If you need a thread safe dictionary use a `ConcurrentDictionary`. If you need an immutable dictionary use `ImmutableDictionary`, which is just thread-safe as side-effect (if you can't modify the original instance there is no multi-threading issue).

Comment: @TimSchmelter I can understand that. but why ImmutableDictionary is a better choice when the updates are not constant? Maybe immutable dictionary has better performance in that scenario?

Comment: It's a better choice because it guarantees that it is never modified(if that is important). A ConcurrentDictionary can never guarantee this. But it allows to create new ImmutableDictionary instances with the `Add` or `Remove` methods

Comment: @TimSchmelter got it, thanks

Comment: [What is the difference between mutable and immutable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3811016/what-is-the-difference-between-mutable-and-immutable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These two classes `ConcurrentDictionary` and `ImmutableDictionary` were compared just because of the simple reason, both are **thread safe**.

However, it is not a good idea to use `ImmutableDictionary` for multi-threading. It is designed to represent data which should be loaded once, and shouldn't be changed / modified later on. Any modifications would lead to creating new instance of `ImmutableDictionary`, which is not really efficient.

Comment: Correctly implemented immutable types are GREAT to go with multitheading. The only problem there that C#'s implementation is far from being even acceptable.

Comment: and the book says that it is not so wasteful because most of the time immutable collections share most of their memory

Comment: As was mentioned by @Tim Schmelter - immutability guarantees that collection never be modified, so - I agree, definitely there would not be any issues with synchronization of threads using immutable types. Another thing that question was about C# implementation, not general best-practices of thread-safe collections.

Comment: @Nico, here is comparison [ConcurrentDictionary vs. Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/when-to-use-a-thread-safe-collection#concurrentdictionary-vs-dictionary) and here [ImmutableDictionaries vs Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795189.aspx). In short - ImmutableDictionaries in most cases **slower** than Dictionary, same time ConcurrentDictionary has **better** or same performance.

Comment: @Alex  Can we interpret that the ImmutableDictionary is not always a better choice if the updates are not constant, it's only better when 'immutable' is important?

Comment: @Nico, I believe so. Referring again to Tim Schmelter - thread-safe just a  side-effect of immutability.

Comment: The thread-safe aspect is only relevant for *true* immutable types. I've seen arguments for why you can call a type *with no observable changes* can be called immutable even though the internals mutate. These objects are obviously not implicitly thread-safe just because they are "immutable."

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, you are definitely right if we are talking about "immutable" in general and it's different possible implementations, however Nico were asking about specific C#/.Net collections.

Comment: I would like to add a comment on the "Any modifications would lead to creating new instance of `ImmutableDictionary`, which is not really efficient", this notion is not entirely true. The `ImmutableDictionary` is backed by an AVL tree. When you modify the content of `ImmutableDictionary`, the only thing is newly allocated is the new node. THERE IS NO NEW INSTANCE OF `ImmutableDictionary` IS CREATED. When you say the `ImmutableDictionary` slower, it's due to the process of balancing the tree. It isn't due to the whole dictionary is freshly created.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable can't be changed, i.e. no add/remove can alter **existing** dictionary, rather would create a new one shipping all but deleted item. Concurrency proceeds on the `lock { }` statement which has nothing to do with immutability. Locks are necessary to manage write operations done by more than single thread to the same memory piece (i.e. same object).

Comment: I dont understand this answer

Comment: Then ask a question.

Comment: what means: _"create a new one shipping all but deleted item"_? What means _"Concurrency proceeds on the lock { } statement"_? (`ConcurrentDictionary` doesn't use a `lock` and you also dont need to use yourself). `ImmutableDictionary` also doesn't need a `lock`(/afaik) and is thread-safe anyway

Comment: Oh really? Try to decompile and see what TryRemoveInternal does. Regarding getting new instance as a result of deletion: whenever you decide to change the content of immutable object, you never modify existing one, you get a new one containing all the items **except ** the one you deleted. Thus nothing ever changes: it looks like it is, but in reality you create new objects.

Comment: Accidently posted my comment as an answer and now not able to remove it from my application. It's quite limited in actions.

Comment: Even if a `lock` is used there, that's an implementation detail which is not important for the user. My point was that it's confusing if you try to explain the difference between `ConcurrentDictionary` and `ImmutableDictionary` with a `lock`. OP didn't ask us to explain him the `lock`

Comment: No it's not. Immutability has nothing to do with locking, though concurrency does. That's the key difference.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov ok, i can understand what you mean now. btw, others won't see the answer posted improperly, dont worry :)